# Ruby progressbar with down gem

Tags: ruby, download, progress-bar

I am implementing a file downloader by using the `down` gem.

I need to add a progress bar to my program for fancy outputs. I found a gem called `ruby-progressbar`. However, I couldn't integrate it to my code base even though I followed the instructions documented on the official site. Here's what I have done so far:

First, I thought of using [progress_proc](https://github.com/janko/down#progress). It was a bad idea because `progress_proc` returns chunked partial of the data.

Second, I [streamed](https://github.com/janko/down#streaming) the data and built an idea on calculating chunked data. It worked well actually, but it smells bad to me.

Plus, here is the small part of my code base. I hope it helps you understand the concept.

```rb
progressbar = ProgressBar.create(title: 'File 1')
Down.download(url, progress_proc: ->(progress) { progressbar.progress = progress }) # It doesn't work
```

```rb
progressbar = ProgressBar.create(title: 'File 1')
file = Down.open(url, progress_proc: ->(progress) { progressbar.progress = progress })
chunked = 0
loop do
  break if file.eof?

  file.read(1024)
  chunked += 1024

  progressbar.progress = (chunked / file.size) * 100
end

# This worked well as I remember. It can be faulty because I wrote it down without testing.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the HTTP protocol, there are two different ways on how a client can determine the full length of a response:

1. In the most common case, the entire response is sent by the server in one go. Here, the length of the response body in bytes is set in the `Content-Length` header of the response. Thus, if the response is not chunked, you can get the value of this header and read the response in one go as it is sent by the server.
2. The second option is for the server to send a chunked response. Here, the server sends chunks of the entire response, one after another. Each chunk is prefixed with the length of the chunk. However, the client has no way to know how many chunks there are in total, nor how large the total response may be. Often, this is even unknown to the server as the first chunks are already sent before the entire response is available to the server.

The down gem follows these two approaches by offering two interfaces:

In the first case (i.e. if the content length of the entire response is known), the gem will call the given `content_length_proc` once.

In the second case, as the entire length of the response is unknown before it was received in total, the `down` gem calls the `progress_proc` once for each chunk received. In this case, it is up to you to show something useful. In general, you can NOT show a progress bar as a percentage of completion here.